# Can I use google analytics in an app released for the kindle fire store?

Tags: android, google-play-services, kindle

I currently have an app on the play store using google analytics. I would like to modify and release that app for the kindle app store and still be able to use GA. I understand that this depends on play services to work correctly. Obviously there are no play services on a kindle device but is there a way to include them with my app. Maybe via the play-services.jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me quote the official **[google analytics sdk v4 guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)**:

> Note: Google Analytics can be used and will work on devices that do
>   not have Google Play Services. In this case you still download and use
>   the Google Play Services SDK and Google Analytics will automatically
>   fall back to local dispatching.

==> It will also track Amazon Kindle / Fire Phone etc.

I have uploaded apps with analytics v4 to amazon and works fine. They even have a device icon for Kindle fire in the google analytics devices section ;-)

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity - I'm using this plugin for our cordova app - [link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin/tree/GA-3.0) , but I cannot see record in our analytics, when running our app locally via USB. Are you using cordova/phonegap plugin perhaps?

Comment: It will also track Fire Phone etc... I have seen pictures and heard stories but never seen a Fire Phone in real life.